# Interaction with web elements using C# not working

Tags: c#, html

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
```

It's not opening Google but this is working fine in Windows form application:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

How can I open the browser using class `WebBrowser` and interact with the HTML elements using C#.

I need to access the attribute values for HTML elements and set values for HTML elements.

Comment: You probably mean it doesn't display it on screen.  Which is expected.  `WebBrowser` is a control that is meant to be added to a `ControlCollection` - like `Form.Controls`

Comment: yes i was expecting it to display on screen.Thanks for the reply @SamAxe :) .Now i can navigate to site from web browser control added in the form.But how can i capture mouse click event inside web browser control.Currently I am not able to capture click event inside browser control.

Comment: You should do some Googling for that.  It will probably involve some kind of javascript/C# bridge.